# SemaphoreSlim travando o método

Tags: c#, async

Estou utilizando SemaphoreSlim para fazer o "lock" de alguns métodos da minha Web-API, até que funcionou corretamente porém tem momentos em que estes mesmos métodos ficam totalmente travados, pelo postman quando eu executo fica um loading e depois de algum tempo retorna o erro.

Segue o código

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlimScheduling = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    ...//outros métodos

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ConfirmScheduling(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            await semaphoreSlimScheduling.WaitAsync();

            //código....

            semaphoreSlimScheduling.Release();
            return Json(new { error = false, message = "Sucesso" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            semaphoreSlimScheduling.Release();
            return Json(new { error = true, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }   
}
```

Apenas e um outro método está utilizando o wait do SemaphoreSlim. Os outros métodos eu não estou fazendo este travamento. Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento está correto. Quando chamada await semaphoreSlimScheduling.WaitAsync() a thread vai ser suspensa até o retorno da task. Dependendo do que tu estiveres fazendo, pode ocorrer demora ou até mesmo falha em conseguir o lock (intermitência postman). Sugiro duas coisas:

- Colocar um timeout para o lock (sobrecarga do método WaitAsync()), evitando que a task fique aguardando infinitamente
- Atribuir o retorno do WaitAsync e verificar se retorna true (lock acquired) ou false (falha no lock).